# How to deal with double quotes in a comparison using javascript with a csv file

Tags: javascript, csv

I want to compare a user's shopping item to a CSV file. For this it will sift through that file and if the user's item matches a string in the CSV file, I want to do something.

So far I have the ability to check the user's items and sift through the CSV file. My problem is the site I'm working on as over 9000 products some with measurements within their title so they'll use doubles i.e.
`Product item A 1/2"`. When using quotes in the CSV file it seems to return it as 2 double quotes which is making the comparison part a little tricky. How can I overcome this issue?

HTML

```
 <div class="item-options">
             <!--START: itemnamelink--><a href="product.asp?itemid=[ITEM_CATALOGID]">[ITEM_NAME]</a><!--END: itemnamelink-->
             <!--START: itemnamenolink--><span id="Span1">[ITEM_NAME]</span><!--END: itemnamenolink-->
             <!--START: itemoptions-->
             <br />
             <a href="#" onclick="toggleProdOptions('opt[ITEM_ID]')">View/Hide options</a><br />
             <div id="opt[ITEM_ID]" name="opt[ITEM_ID]" style="display:none;">[OPTIONS]</div>
             <!--END: itemoptions-->
             <!--START: recurring_frequency-->
             <br />
             This item will Autoship every <strong>[recurring_frequency]</strong>
             <!--END: recurring_frequency--></div>
         </div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var itemToStore = document.getElementsByClassName("item-options");

    localStorage.setItem("itemToStore", JSON.stringify(itemToStore));

    var retrieved = localStorage.getItem("itemToStore");

    for (var i = 0; i < itemToStore .length; i++) {
        var itemName= itemToStore [i].innerText;
        var name = (""+itemName).replace(/['"]+/g,'');
        console.log("Name: " + name);
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "assets/exports/pipe.csv",
        dataType:"text",
        success: function(data) { 
            var code = name.split("\n");

            for(var i=0;i<code.length;i++) {
                code[i]="\""+code[i]+"\"";
            }

            var pipeString = code.join("\n");

            var test = "Pipe";
            console.log(test);
            // Flag that value found
            var found = false;
            // Remove \n and split by ,
            var listPipe = data.split('\r\n').map(function(row) {
                return row.split(',');
            });

            var pipeList = (""+listPipe).replace(/['"]+/g,'');

            console.log(pipeList);

            // Array of arrays like be generated
            for (var i = 0; i < listPipe.length; i++) {
                if ($.inArray(test, listPipe) !== -1) {
                    found = true;
                    console.log("found");
                }
                else {
                    console.log("not found");
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

CSV FILE
[image: csv file]

console.log results
[image]

Comment: I find the question very confusing. What does your CSV look like? What do your product items look like? How exactly is your code behaving now? How do you expect your code to behave?

Comment: Hiya Freeman. I added pictures down the bottom to help shed some light. My cvs file is the 'CSV file line', my product item is 'Product name'.

Comment: Well, it was the image part that got me confused actually :). In your first CSV file image, for example, I do not see any `"` character. Even though there are no `"` characters there, your console log is showing `""` sequences everywhere, like `"" 512""` etc.

Comment: Ah i see, i've updated my OP to try and make it clearer. So I'm wanting to basically compare the item name to the name category in the csv file. I want to be able to detect when it's the same and when it's not. Double quotes on things seems to be making it overly difficult. For now i've made a test variable named "Pipe", which should prove an exact match to the category strings.

Answer (score 0):

you could make a function which will escape the quote characters. For example, the esc_quote can do the trick for you. Hope this helps.

```
function esc_quote(text){
   return text.replace("\"", "\\\"");
}
```